# Trigger-Method of WebControl is not fired

Tags: .net, asp.net, page-lifecycle, lifecycle

this is my scenario:
i have a page with a placeholder. the page adds dynimcally different kinds of controls (we wan't to display some data - getting the id via querystring or postback, as we also have a tree) to this placeholder.
the added controls all, more or less, contain a textbox (name of the displaying element), checkbox (active-state of the displaying element) and a save-button which fires a method inside this webcontrol.

now my problem is really obvious:
as i'm adding the control dynamically (and for every condition: !Postback and Postback), the save-method inside the so added control, won't fire - regardless what i do ...

i'm simply to stupid to get the trick :)

some behind-the-scene-infos (workflow):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.SelectedElement = SomeMagicMethod();
    }
}

protected void NodeSelected(object sender, TreeViewNodeEventArgs e)
{
    this.SelectedElement = SomeOtherMagicMethod();
}

protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    // we have to take this life-cycle!
    if (this.SelectedElement!= null)
    {
        this.DisplayElement();
    }
}

private void DisplayElement()
{
    var UC = this.LoadControl(UCPath) as DataTypeUC;
    if (UC == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    UC.ID = EditCampaignFolderUCID;
    UC.SetData(this.SelectedElement);
    UC.DataBind();
    this.phContent.Controls.Add(UC);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the markup and code behind for the user control you are adding? /Asger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick is: reinstatiate everything in oninit, and in the order as the viewstate was saved at the last request ... tricky tricky

Answer (score 0):

While adding controls dynamically, you'll also have to wire up the event of the save button everytime (that is, if the save button is being generated dynamically).